# What is the binary file format for an iPhone application targeting the Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When building an iPhone application with the Simulator as the target, what is the file format of the resulting binary?  Where can I find the compiled application?

Comment: I guess the output format is .dSym file

Comment: Is it possible to extract that .dsym file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator runs a stripped down version of the same os that any iDevice runs. Therefore it takes a compiled .app file and runs that. The input is whatever code you used to write your app.

Comment: Press run to compile and run your app. Select the simulator as your destination if you want to run on the simulator

Comment: Is there any possibilty to extract that .app file and make to run on other iphone simulator with out the source code?

Comment: It's stored on your harddrive: /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ works for me, replacing USER_NAME with my name

Comment: How to extract that .app file ,since I ven't seen any .app file inside my project folder?

Comment: @icoder The .app isn't in the project folder. It's buried somewhere in the ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ folder, like James mentioned. And there's no "extraction" needed: just copy the file. You could probably find it in Spotlight by looking for your app name.